# Pivoting data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data as a pandas dataframe:

```
               type      exdiv    paydate  amount
declared                                         
2014-01-31    final 2014-03-03 2014-03-10    3.10
2014-06-27  interim 2014-08-11 2014-08-18    1.55
2015-01-30    final 2015-03-02 2015-03-09    2.33
2015-01-30    final 2015-03-02 2015-03-09    0.77
2015-06-26  interim 2015-08-07 2015-08-17    1.80
2016-01-29    final 2016-02-29 2016-03-07    3.45
```

The 2015-01-30 entry is repeated twice. What is the easiest way to sum up that row so that I only have one entry equal to 3.10 for 2015-01-30?

I've tried the following so far:

```
x=pd.pivot_table(df, values='amount', index=['exdiv','paydate','type'], columns=[])
```

But this creates a multi-index and I can't use the current index column ('declared').

I know I can add the index as a normal column, run the command and try to convert the multi-index back to a single index, but I'm sure there must be a better method in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['amount'] = df.groupby(level=0)['amount'].transform(sum)
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['declared','type','exdiv','paydate'])
print (df)
     declared     type       exdiv     paydate  amount
0  2014-01-31    final  2014-03-03  2014-03-10    3.10
1  2014-06-27  interim  2014-08-11  2014-08-18    1.55
2  2015-01-30    final  2015-03-02  2015-03-09    3.10
4  2015-06-26  interim  2015-08-07  2015-08-17    1.80
5  2016-01-29    final  2016-02-29  2016-03-07    3.45
```

Or add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `aggfunc=sum` to [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
x=pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(), 
                 values='amount', 
                 index=['declared','exdiv','paydate','type'], 
                 aggfunc=sum).reset_index()
print (x)
     declared       exdiv     paydate     type  amount
0  2014-01-31  2014-03-03  2014-03-10    final    3.10
1  2014-06-27  2014-08-11  2014-08-18  interim    1.55
2  2015-01-30  2015-03-02  2015-03-09    final    3.10
3  2015-06-26  2015-08-07  2015-08-17  interim    1.80
4  2016-01-29  2016-02-29  2016-03-07    final    3.45
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I settled for transform with drop duplicates.

Comment: Glad can help you!